# .NET - покрасить границы маркеров цветом палитры

Tags: c#, .net, графика, диаграммы

Я создал производный класс от `Series` со своими настройками, указал там, что мне нужен Spline, нужные толщины и т.д., но хотелось бы еще, чтобы цвет обводки маркера `MarkerBorderColor` был как у графика.
Я пробовал присваивать ему значение `Color`, но т.к. оно по умолчанию пустое, то должен помогать метод `ApplyPaletteColors()`, но это не помогает.

```cs
public class CustomSeries : Series
{
    public CustomSeries(string name, Chart chart)
    {
        Name = name;
        chart.ApplyPaletteColors();        // Т.к. значение Color пустое, то
                                           // по идее этот метод его заполнит

        MarkerColor = chart.BackColor;     // Сам маркер должен быть цвета фона
        MarkerBorderColor = Color;         // А обводка - цвета линии
    }
}
```

> Картинка
>   [image: Картинка]

Comment: Может, помимо цвета указать и толщину?

Comment: Толщины тоже указаны, в коде я это просто не стал показывать. Если присваивать обводке какой-то конкретный цвет - то все видно.